# Problem with List

Tags: java

I am a java newbie, and having some issue with "java.util.List".Below is my code,where I'm trying to create a list of objects but the result I am getting is undesired.Can you please help me in solving the issue.

```
import java.util.*;

class  testMap
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        HashMap<String,Object> childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        List <Object> actList= new ArrayList <Object> ();

        for (int x=0;x<2 ;x++ ){

        if(x==0){

        childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x);
        childRowMap.put("endDate","endDate"+x);
        childRowMap.put("encodedValue"," enc"+x);

        }
        else if (x==1){
        childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x);
        childRowMap.put("endDate","endDate"+x);
        childRowMap.put("encodedValue"," enc"+x);
        }
        System.out.println("Adding object in the postition "+ x);
        actList.add(x,childRowMap);

        }
                System.out.println(actList);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Adding object in the postition 0
Adding object in the postition 1
[{encodedValue= enc1, startDate=startDate1, endDate=endDate1}, {encodedValue= en
c1, startDate=startDate1, endDate=endDate1}]
```

===============

Why I am not getting objects with different values.Kindly helping me out in figuring the problem with my code..

Comment: It would be better (more type-safe) to declare `actList` as a `List<Map<String,Object>>` instead of a `List<Object>` and initialize it accordingly.

Comment: your `if(x==0){` and `else if (x==1){` blocks are also completely redundant. Get rid of the if/else and just keep the body of one of them.  That's what `for` loops are for.

Answer (score 6):

**You're adding `childRowMap` twice.**

Note that you're adding the *reference* to `childRowMap`. This means that changes to the map will be visible from both reference at index 0 and index 1, and that's why it looks like you've added two identical objects.

You could fix it by creating a new map each iteration in the loop:

```
import java.util.*;

class testMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

.-------
|
|       List<Object> actList = new ArrayList<Object>();
|       
|       for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
|           
'---------> HashMap<String, Object> childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            if (x == 0) {
                childRowMap.put("startDate", "startDate" + x);
                childRowMap.put("endDate", "endDate" + x);
                childRowMap.put("encodedValue", " enc" + x);
            } else if (x == 1) {
                childRowMap.put("startDate", "startDate" + x);
                childRowMap.put("endDate", "endDate" + x);
                childRowMap.put("encodedValue", " enc" + x);
            }
            System.out.println("Adding object in the postition " + x);
            actList.add(x, childRowMap);

        }
        System.out.println(actList);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Adding object in the postition 0
Adding object in the postition 1
[{encodedValue= enc0, startDate=startDate0, endDate=endDate0},
 {encodedValue= enc1, startDate=startDate1, endDate=endDate1}]
```

Comment: Well then, that example is much prettier than mine. Anyone who takes the time to draw out ASCII arrows for moving code around has my +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reinitialize your map on every iteration. Put the initialization inside the `for` loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    HashMap<String,Object> childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that childRowMap is the same instance, created in your first line of code. When you go through the for loop, you aren't creating a new instance, you're just putting new values in the existing HashMap. That means that the ArrayList, performing a referential check, sees that the object is already in the list and doesn't add it twice.

Simple fix: move the initialization inside the for loop, so on each iteration through the loop, the HashMap is re-instantiated.

```
class testMap { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,Object> childRowMap;     
        List <Object> actList= new ArrayList <Object> ();    

        for (int x=0;x<2 ;x++ ){
            childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            if(x==0){
                childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x);
                childRowMap.put("endDate","endDate"+x);
                childRowMap.put("encodedValue"," enc"+x);    
            } else if (x==1){
                childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x);
                childRowMap.put("endDate","endDate"+x);
                childRowMap.put("encodedValue"," enc"+x);    
            }
            System.out.println("Adding object in the postition "+ x);
            actList.add(x,childRowMap);
        }
        System.out.println(actList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code. It can all be compacted like this:

```
List <Map<String,Object>> actList= new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> ();

for (int x=0;x<2 ;x++ ){
    Map<String,Object> childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x);
    childRowMap.put("endDate","endDate"+x);
    childRowMap.put("encodedValue"," enc"+x);
    System.out.println("Adding object in the postition "+ x);
    actList.add(childRowMap);
}
System.out.println(actList);
```

Few other things:

- As a Java standard your class name should start with upper case so consider `TestMap` instead of `testMap`
- Type of Map variable should be generic `Map` instead of an implementation like `HashMap` (I have corrected that in my answer).
- Consider declaring List as of more specific type `List<Map<String,Object>>` instead of generic Object for type safety.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, hash map keys should be unique, simplest fix is add this line

```
HashMap<String,Object> childRowMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

at the start of the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Maps store by Key:Value pairs. In your code when you do

```
childRowMap.put("startDate","startDate"+x)
```

it is doing this:

```
childRowMap.put(Key,Value)
```

So basically you are setting the key startDate to be equal to startDate0 (when x is 0). When you loop through the second time, you are setting the key startDate to be equal to startDate1 (because x is 1). Now whenever you look up startDate, it will only have startDate1 stored because startDate0 was overwritten because you only have 1 Map.

You can fix this by either reinitializing your Map every time you loop through or by using new and unique Key's to each Value you put in the Map.